# How can I use the Traveling Salesperson Problem (TSP) with a List of Haversine Distances?

Tags: python, r, geospatial, traveling-salesman, haversine

I have a list of haversine distances between customers and their respective salespersons and I would like to apply the TSP algorithm to optimize each salesperson's distance traveled in a given day. What would be the best approach to solving this problem in R or Python?

Note: I do not need to visualize this through any map, I just need to shortest distance traveled between each customer starting and ending with the salesperson location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of strategies you can use to solve this problem, such as (1) approximation algorithms, (2) exact approaches, and, of course, (3) heuristic/metaheuristic approaches. Note that, the optimal solution of a given instance is guaranteed to be achieved only using exact approaches.
Regarding each strategy, bellow follows some links that might help you:

1. Approximation algorithms: There is a famous approximation algorithm for the metric TSP, i.e. when the graph is metric, called [Christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm). But for a general graph, there is no approximation algorithm, unless P = NP (you can check the proof of this theorem [here](http://www14.in.tum.de/personen/khan/Arindam%20Khan_files/2.%20metric%20TSP.pdf), at section 2);
2. Exact approaches: For the TSP, this strategy usually divides itself into two categories (but not limited): [dynamic programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaXsJJh-Q5Y) and [integer programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRJSFtscnbA);
3. Heuristic/Metaheuristic approaches: I will not enter in details about it since there are a big number of heuristics and metaheuristics available for the TSP (you can check it by yourself [here](https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1&q=heuristics%20and%20metaheuristics%20tsp)).

As you can see, my answer is very open, since your question is very open. So, if you want to get a more precise answer, you need to specify exactly what you need/want.

Comment: One more thing, maybe move this question to the OR Stack exchange (https://or.stackexchange.com/), would be better, since this question seems to be more related to the OR environment.